# How to Revert Database Changes Made in a Session Without Using Transaction Management?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, rollback

I'm working on a simple Java application where I need to perform database operations using Java Persistence API (JPA). I want to know if there's a way to revert changes made in the session if an error occurs during the process, without relying on explicit transaction management.

Here is the function that does the db transaction.

```
  public void insertOrUpdateEntity(final Object entityObject) throws SqlException {
    Transaction transaction = this.session.beginTransaction();
    try {
      this.session.merge(entityObject);
      transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (PersistenceException e) {
      if (transaction != null) {
        transaction.rollback();
      }
      this.session.flush();
    }
  }
```

Here is the function that uses above function

```
  private void performDatabaseUpdate() {
    DataBaseOperations dbOperations = null;
    DataBaseConfigurator dbConfiguration = this.databaseConnectionDetails.getDatabaseConnection();

    try {
      dbOperations = dbConfiguration.getSession();

      dbOperations.insertOrUpdateEntity(entityObject1);
      dbOperations.insertOrUpdateEntity(entityObject2);
      dbOperations.insertOrUpdateEntity(entityObject3);
      dbOperations.insertOrUpdateEntity(entityObject4);
      
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
          e.getMessage();
    }
    finally {
      dbOperations.close();
    }
  }
```

Specifically, I'm looking for features or techniques within JPA that allow me to:

Begin a session for performing database operations.
Save a series of annotated entity objects in the session.
Revert changes made in the session if any exception occurs during the saving process, ensuring that changes are not persisted to the database.
Which means, when any exception occurs while saving the`entityObject4` i want to revert back the changes made into the database wrt `entityObject1, entityObject2, entityObject3`.

I tried following

```
 Transaction transaction = this.session.beginTransaction();
    try {
      this.session.merge(entityObject);
      transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (PersistenceException e) {
      if (transaction != null) {
        transaction.rollback();
      }
      **this.session.flush();**
    }
```

Is there any built-in functionality or recommended approach within JPA to achieve this, without explicitly managing transactions? Any insights or examples demonstrating how to implement this in a simple Java application would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: recover from backup?

Comment: @P.Salmon, No, Its a use-case. I have 10 tables in the DB that are unidirectionally linked. I need to add the data into all tables for each run of the application.

If any exception occurs while inserting the data at any tables instance, I don't want any update in the DB for that run.

Comment: If your code always looks like your sample code, you can write your own "merge"-function (and/or your own functions for all similar situations) that will include transaction handling. Otherwise: how will your code/java/JPA know to which point you want to revert to (e.g. the last 4 changes? everything since the program started? Everything since thursday 12:00?) To tell your code that, you will probably need some marker, as well as an "now its done" marker. This will almost look as if you were using transactions to begin with.

Comment: MySQL is happy to have a transaction span multiple tables as long as it does not last more than a few seconds.  In other words, I don't see a problem.  (Or maybe JPA is getting in the way?)

Comment: @RickJames, I have corrected the code part in question and added actual use case.
Could you share any possible way to achieve this requirement.

Comment: @Solarflare, I have corrected the sample code and now i can confirm my code always look as my sample code. What do u suggest to achieve this requirement.

Comment: "without explicitly managing transactions" -- I doubt it.  You need control, as you wrote it.